# c++ boost asio serial communication "cannot access private member" in basic_serial_port.hpp

Tags: serial-port, arduino, boost-asio, private-members

I'm writing a C++ program to communicate with multiple devices - an Arduino Pro Mini w/ATmega328 and an Arduino Uno with GPS shield - simultaneously via COM port, and I'm using the boost::asio package. I'm no C++ guru, so I occasionally get muddled trying to figure out where/when to pass by reference or value; I think this is one of those cases.

Here's the code that sets up the serial ports for communication

```
std::string IMU_COM_PORT = "COM5"; // or whatever... it varies
int IMU_BAUD_RATE = 57600;
std::string ARDUINO_COM_PORT = "COM3"; // also varies
int ARDUINO_BAUD_RATE = 115200;

int main() {
    std::vector<boost::thread *> sensorThreads;
    int sensorThreadCount = 0;

    using namespace::boost::asio;

    // get the COM port handle for the IMU sensor
    boost::asio::io_service IMU_io;
    boost::asio::serial_port IMU_port(IMU_io);
    IMU_port.open(IMU_COM_PORT);
    if (!IMU_port.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Failed to connect to IMU." << endl;
    }
    else {
        IMU_port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(IMU_BAUD_RATE));
        // the IMU has to be put into triggered output mode with a specific command: #o0
        // to put it back into continuous output mode we can use this command: #o1
        std::string IMU_init_cmd = "#o0";
        boost::asio::write(IMU_port, boost::asio::buffer(IMU_init_cmd.c_str(), IMU_init_cmd.size()));
        // now the IMU should be ready

        sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, IMU_port));
        sensorThreadCount++;
    }

    // get the COM port handle for the ARDUINO board with GPS sensor
    boost::asio::io_service ARDUINO_io;
    boost::asio::serial_port ARDUINO_port(ARDUINO_io);
    ARDUINO_port.open(ARDUINO_COM_PORT);
    if (!ARDUINO_port.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Failed to connect to ARDUINO." << endl;
    }
    else {
        ARDUINO_port.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(ARDUINO_BAUD_RATE));
        // now the ARDUINO w/GPS sensor should be ready

        sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testGPSThread, ARDUINO_port));
        sensorThreadCount++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sensorThreadCount; i++) {
        sensorThreads[i]->join();
        delete sensorThreads[i];
    }
}
```

My two test thread functions are basically identical, the only difference being the byte(s) they send to the devices indicating that something (my computer) is waiting to read data from them.

```
void testIMUThread(boost::asio::serial_port *port) {
    while(true) { cout << readCOMLine(port, "#f") << endl; }
}
void testGPSThread(boost::asio::serial_port *port) {
    while(true) { cout << readCOMLine(port, "r") << endl; }
}
```

And both of these test threads make use of a single function that does the serial read/writes.

```
std::string readCOMLine(boost::asio::serial_port *port, std::string requestDataCmd) {
    char c;
    std::string s;
    boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(requestDataCmd.c_str(), requestDataCmd.size()));
    while(true) {
        boost::asio::read(port, boost::asio::buffer(&c,1));
        switch(c) {
            case '\r': break;
            case '\n': return s;
            default: s += c;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code does not compile but instead produces the following (in MSVC2010):
`Error  11  error C2248: 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>::basic_io_object' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::asio::basic_io_object<IoObjectService>'  C:\boost_1_51_0\boost\asio\basic_serial_port.hpp`

The error message is rather unhelpful - to me, at least - as I've not been able to track down the root cause. What am I missing here?

Thanks for your help.

---

***Edit: Solutions** (thanks to Sam Miller)*

Using pass-by-reference (i.e. `boost::ref()`)

```
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, IMU_port));
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, ARDUINO_port));
```

in `main()` become

```
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, boost::ref(IMU_port)));
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, boost::ref(ARDUINO_port)));
```

Then the workhorse and thread functions are modified as such

```
std::string readCOMLine(boost::asio::serial_port &port, std::string requestDataCmd) {
    char c;
    std::string s;
    boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(requestDataCmd.c_str(), requestDataCmd.size()));
    while(true) {
        boost::asio::read(port, boost::asio::buffer(&c,1));
        switch(c) {
            case '\r': break;
            case '\n': return s;
            default: s += c;
        }
    }
}
void testIMUThread(boost::asio::serial_port &port) {
    while(true) { cout << readCOMLine(port, "#f") << endl; }
}
void testGPSThread(boost::asio::serial_port &port) {
    while(true) { cout << readCOMLine(port, "r") << endl; }
}
```

On the other hand, if using pass-by-pointer, the thread initializations in `main()` look like this

```
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, &IMU_port));
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, &ARDUINO_port));
```

And the thread functions like this

```
void testIMUThread(boost::asio::serial_port *port) {
    while(true) { cout << readCOMLine(port, "#f") << endl; }
}
void testGPSThread(boost::asio::serial_port *port) {
    while(true) { cout << readCOMLine(port, "r") << endl; }
}
```

But I have to make some additional changes (on top of the input parameter modification) to the function that does all of the work - namely the read/write calls.

```
std::string readCOMLine(boost::asio::serial_port *port, std::string requestDataCmd) {
    char c;
    std::string s;
    port->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(requestDataCmd.c_str(), requestDataCmd.size())); // this line
    while(true) {
        port->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(&c,1)); // and this line
        switch(c) {
            case '\r': break;
            case '\n': return s;
            default: s += c;
        }
    }
}
```

Both solutions compile and seem to work for my purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::asio::serial_port` objects are noncopyable

You should pass a reference

```
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, boost::ref(IMU_port)));
```

or a pointer

```
sensorThreads.push_back(new boost::thread(testIMUThread, &IMU_port));
```

here's a [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=61ed0b993eab082306ba542dde2d87bd-ad052fee86f964776c0381d4097909ea) showing both methodologies.

Comment: Hey Sam, thanks for your response. One of my original attempts to resolve the problem was to pass the pointer `&IMU_port`, but that required I change the code that makes use of the pointer (i.e. `asio::write(port, buffer)` becomes `port->write_some(buffer)`). I guess I did something wrong there, too, because I couldn't get that working either. With your examples I figured it out, though - both methods. Thank you!